# I am repairing an automotive board. I want to know about the manufacturer of a crystal oscillator

Tags: identification, oscillator, datasheet, crystal

I want a datasheet for the below attached image crystal oscillator. It will be helpful if someone find it. I want to use same manufacturer crystal.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the dimensions of the crystal? That would narrow the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer is [Hosonic Elec](http://www.hosonic.com/en/). They seem use similar markings for different crystals, so it's impossible to tell the exact model without additional information, like the size. Here are the markings of the [E2SB24E000008E](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Crystals_Hosonic-Elec-E2SB24E000008E_C5241183.html) as example to show that it's the right manufacturer:

[image]